# Unity files not being ignored properly by git

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore, git-status

I'm working with Unity in a group, and because of what I've read in several places, we put the following lines into our `.gitignore`

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild
[Ll]ibrary/
sysinfo.txt
*.stackdump

# ============================================= #
# Visual Studio / MonoDevelop / Rider generated #
# ============================================= #
[Ee]xported[Oo]bj/
.vs/
/*.userprefs
/*.csproj
/*.pidb
/*.suo
/*.sln*
/*.user
/*.unityproj
/*.booproj
/.idea*/

# ============ #
# OS generated #
# ============ #
.DS_Store*
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
[Tt]humbs.db
[Dd]esktop.ini
```

When I clone the project, the working directory is clean, but as soon as I open this project in Unity, I see tons of files were marked as changed in `git status`:
[image: git status]

Why are these files being added even though they are in the `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Were they by any chance added before you created the .gitignore file?

If so, then remove them:

```
git rm --cached [file]
```

After that make a new commit with the changes. That is it, they will be removed and untracked from then on.

Comment: Looking at the history, they were indeed added _before_ the gitignore. I ran `git rm -r --cached .` then `git add .` That seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

That's a classic! If you added a gitignore after git started tracking your files, it won't release the files it is already tracking. You need to "reset" it by doing the following:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Gitignore now working!"
```

Will take care of everything. **HOWEVER** make sure you commit any changes before doing this, as they will otherwise be deleted.